# Evaluating the model stability using bootstrapping

Tags: machine-learning, bootstrap, uncertainty

I need help with the following.

Using our alternate data for external clients, we have built a model for identifying fraudulent customers (classification).

we used the auto-ml package to arrive at the best model and gave the results back by scoring the client's holdout data that was without the target.

Now, the client wants us to check on model stability by performing 50 bootstrapping and we are not sure how to benchmark the stability after the bootstrapping.

Any guidance on the same would be appreciated.

Note : the client is from a banking institution.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrapping involves randomly resampling a dataset with replacement to generate multiple bootstrap samples. These samples can be used to estimate the sampling distribution of a statistic or to evaluate the stability of a model.

Here are some general steps you can follow to evaluate the stability of your model using bootstrapping:

1. Randomly sample your data with replacement to create multiple bootstrap samples.
2. For each bootstrap sample, fit your model and evaluate its performance on a validation set or using cross-validation.
3. Calculate a performance metric for each bootstrap sample.
4. Examine the distribution of the performance metric across the bootstrap. If the distribution is narrow and symmetric, it indicates that the model is stable. If the distribution is wide or skewed, it indicates that the model is unstable.
5. Optionally, you can calculate confidence intervals for the performance metric using the bootstrap samples. This will give you an estimate of the range of values within which the true population parameter is likely to fall.